# Laravel deploy to Shared Hosting (Hostgator) CPANEL error

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

i thank you guys in advance for the help.

I'm deploying a laravel app to hostgator shared hosting, using CPanel and after everything, i'm having an issue with it.

```
The error message: Warning: Declaration of Illuminate\Http\Request::get($key, $default = NULL) should be compatible with Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::get(string $key, $default = NULL) in /home1/ipixels/mrm.ipixels.com.br/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php on line 20.
```

Google and laravel forums we're of no help and i'm not sure what i'm missing here.

Comment: What version of laravel and php?

Comment: Laravel 6 and PHP 7.2.5.

Comment: Some file has the wrong class extension code. Either you are running different versions (composer packages or php) or your own code is faulty.

Comment: I updated composer and looked trough all my code. Now i'm uploading again to see if there's any change.